# Force validation on submit

Tags: angularjs

I'm validating an input element with the directive below. The problem is that this way it's only executed when the input element is activated. Is there a way to force execute the parsers methods of all input elements of a form?

```
"use strict";

angular.module("kap.directive")
    .directive('kapValidationDuration', ['$timeout', '$log', function ($timeout, $log) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: { minReservationDurationMinutes: '=minReservationDurationMinutes' },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                if (attrs.type === 'radio' || attrs.type === 'checkbox') {
                    return;
                }

                ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                    if(value && !element[0].hidden) {

                        var lTimeValues = value.split(":"),
                        lHoursToMinutes = parseInt(lTimeValues[0], 10) * 60,
                        lMinutes = parseInt(lTimeValues[1], 10),
                        lMinReservationDurationMinutes = parseInt(attrs.minreservationdurationminutes, 10) || 10,
                        lValidity = true;


                    if ((lHoursToMinutes + lMinutes) < lMinReservationDurationMinutes) {
                        lValidity = false;
                    }

                    ctrl.$setValidity('kapValidationDuration', lValidity);
                    }

                    return value;
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that, i.e. validate the initial values as well, you also have to use the `$formatters`. Luckilly, in your case, you just have to `unshift` the *same* function to the `$formatters`, as the one used for the `$parsers`.

The reason is that the parsers are used when going form → model. In general this means data conversion: if the model was a number, the input from the user is always a string and has to be converted; the errors may not only be validation (e.g. "age must be positive") but also parsing (e.g. "'tata' is not a valid number"). The formatters when going model → form. This is, as the name implies, formatting: e.g. a `Date` object may need to be displayed as `dd/MM/yyyy` in my locale (greek), but `MM/dd/yyyy` in other locales.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52dAB/

In the fiddle I am still using two separate functions for the formatters and the parsers, despite them being identical in implementation. Just for the sake of generality.